# Generate Helper handlebars in ember-cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, helper, jsbin

I have followed the [ember guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/writing-helpers/) to create an handlebar helper like in this [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qokoseliwu/edit?html,js,output)

This is the helper

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('format-date', function(format, date) {
  return moment(date).format(format);
});
```

I can successfully reuse in my [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lavajajedi/edit?html,js,output) but i get an error when i apply the same helper in my application, this is the error ***Uncaught TypeError: fn.apply is not a function*** in my helper function , i am not implementing it correctly in my ember-cli

This is the same helper in my application

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('format-date', function(format, date) {
        return moment(date).format(format);
});
```

What's the problem?

I have also used `makeBoundHelper` instead of `registerBoundHelper`

Just to let you know i have generated the ember helper in these steps

1) From command prompt `run ember generate helper "format-date"`

This was the helper generated

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function formatDate(params/*, hash*/) {
  return params;
}
```

I am definitely mistaking the way i am exporting the `format-date` helper

How it should be in my ember-cli?

P.s. I am still using Ember 1.12.0 , i have seen a similar issue [here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/fn-apply-is-not-a-function-trying-to-create-a-handlebars-helper/7947)

Comment: it is definitely due to ember version that you are using, api have changed of making `helpers`, current 2.x api is most simplest `Ember.Helper.helper(your helper code)` if possible upgrade your ember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update to Ember Version 1.13.7 and change the helper to this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function formatDate(params) {
  var date = params[0];
  return moment(date).format('LLL');
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(formatDate);
```

Comment: Do you mean `1.13.7`?

Comment: if you are making moment helper it is better you have a look at https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment first